# typescript only allow circular reference keys from the same object

Tags: typescript

I have an object that describes service definitions. Each service definition may "inject" other service definitions through the optional `dependencies` object.

How can I only allow keys that exist within this object? For example, in the screenshot below, I've defined the service "viewport" which I inject in "clock". Intellisense/autocomplete should only show "viewport".

Is this even possible?

[image]

So in the example above, I would only expect "clock" and "viewport" to appear as possible options for the "dependencies" array. I know clock shouldn't be able to inject itself, but I'm okay with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a generic function to create the config, since it infers the types

```
function createConfiguration<T extends ContainerConfiguration<R>, R extends keyof T>(config: T) {
    return config
}
```

And update your types to take generic arguments

```
type ContainerConfiguration<T extends string | number | symbol = any> = {
    [P in T]: ServiceDefinition<Exclude<T,P>>
}
type ServiceDefinition<T> = {
    class: new (...args: any[]) => any;
    dependencies?: T[]
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gO2AQwJYIgJ3ggZqgcwFdNlhVEAeAFSggA9gIEATAZyjeE3QKgB8oCIgFsARlgGcQ4uABsoAXijIEIAHxKoAbwBQUKAG0AClHRRqAXQBcUAMpYAbqgDGEACIR8CVOSoBRehc5IhYIGgAaY3V1XQBfXVBIeydXDy90XwoEGk1lPQNg5DY2WwwAdygACgA6OuRMAlKVNUNLAEolTVUQAG59KDDIVmYXVAg2AH5bajb43SKSqAA1cfLjOExgHV15xY4YOTgXAGsd+dwiBBc-BCgXTAgyCBx8YlJbmjpGZnZYRBQ6Cwr0IJDI2UoACV1BEoJDvkxWBwThAQHBcBZ1FUXIg3jNOgUoI9gCQ7ji8IR5nIINtoMoHk8mCD3uDEFVCc4IOUwJtgLZCYU5MVmqsuRstgM4hEBsFjid+QNBcLbIc5dKDAYhr9RuNmoYAESy076yyS9VQJhcBUa+5Ckoqo6nc2aiDDMLXXW2A2c7m8-Ww-UIOCQE2S3ZxdpAA)

Comment: This still allows for misconfiguration (ie forgetting to update the dependencies array). Why not simply determine the dependencies based on the parameters the constructor takes?  https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#constructorparameterstype